# What does these in a JavaScript function parameter `{ environment = 'test' } = {}` mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone please help out on these questions, It is more syntactically driven
Below includes the code;

`const makeServer = ({ environment =  'test' } = {}) => {}`

I got this from a tutorial and all I could see here is setting up the default parameter to the function makeServer, I wanted to know that since we have an object as the function parameter, then why do we need to re-assign, another object to it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: `{ environment =  'test' } = {}` means that the first argument may be undefined, and if it is you assign an empty object to it. It is using destructuring assignment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment. The object will have a key `environment` that, if not found, will default to a value of `test`.

Answer (score 1):

They want to `destructure` the argument to the function and give a default parameter if none is provided.

If you don't pass a default argument for the function param you'll get a runtime error when calling a function with no param (or `undefined`).

```
const makeServer = ({ environment =  'test' }) => {}
makeServer();
```

will lead to something similar to this

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'environment')`

Answer (score 0):

You are not re-assigning an empty object to it, you are defining a default value to use in case the function is being explicitly called with an empty object.

[image]